# Convert ArrayList of custom objects to JSON

Tags: java, json

I have an ArrayList of custom Objects. Each of these objects have an arraylist of another custom object. Then these second level of custom objects have an arraylist of another custom object.

This is how the class hierarchy looks like

```
public class Undle {
    private String undleStatus; 
    private ArrayList<ArcelFolder> arcelFolders;

    public ArrayList<ArcelFolder> getArcelFolders() {
        return arcelFolders;
    }
    public void setArcelFolders(ArrayList<ArcelFolder> arcelFolders) {
        this.arcelFolders = arcelFolders;
    }
    //Other getter and setters
}


public class ArcelFolder {
    private ArrayList<ArcelDocument> arcelDocuments;
    private String arcelStatus;
    public String getArcelStatus() {
        return arcelStatus;
    }
    public void setArcelStatus(String arcelStatus) {
        this.arcelStatus = arcelStatus;
    }
    public ArrayList<ArcelDocument> getArcelDocuments() {
        return arcelDocuments;
    }
    public void setArcelDocuments(ArrayList<ArcelDocument> arcelDocuments) {
        this.arcelDocuments = arcelDocuments;
    }
}

public class ArcelDocument {
    private String gain;

    public String getGain() {
        return gain;
    }
    public void setGain(String gain) {
        this.gain = gain;
    }
}
```

I have an arraylist of Undle objects

```
ArrayList<Undle> undleList = new ArrayList<Undle>();
// Create objects of ArcelFolder and ArcelDocument
// Add ArcelDocument list to ArcelFolder
// Add ArcelFolder list to Undle arraylist
```

I would like to convert Undle ArrayList to a JSON. How can I flatten this hierarcical structure of beans and put it in a JSON?

I tried doing something like

```
org.json.simple.JSONObject resultObj = new JSONObject(undleList);
```

and

```
org.json.simple.JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(undleList);
```

But it seems that they work only if a String ArrayList is passed.

Comment: try this: https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: It would be useful to know why the question has been downvoted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
             Type type = new TypeToken<List<Bundle>>() {}.getType();
             String json = gson.toJson(bundleList, type);
             System.out.println(json);
             List<Bundle> fromJson = gson.fromJson(json, type);

             for (Bundle bundle : fromJson) {
                     System.out.println(bundle);
             }
```